# Symfony: on authentication with API Keys how do logout the current user (if already authenticated and not the same)?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I have implemented [API Key Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html) and works fine! But Symfony when the user is already authenticated don't call the pre-authentication mechanism.

It is possible perform the logout of the current user if it is already authenticated?

my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        ACME\FooBundle\Security\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [foo, bar]
        foo:
            id: foo_user_provider
        bar:
            id: bar_user_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
             pattern: ^/
             anonymous: ~
             simple_preauth:
                provider: foo
                authenticator: apikey_authenticator
             form_login:
                 provider: chain_provider
                 remember_me: true
                 check_path: acme_foo_login_check
                 login_path: acme_foo_login
                 default_target_path:   acme_foo_homepage
                 target_path_parameter: _target_path
                 use_referer:           true
                 username_parameter: _username
                 password_parameter: _password
                 success_handler: ACME.security.login_success_handler
             logout:
                 path:   acme_foo_logout
                 target: acme_foo_login
                 invalidate_session: true
                 success_handler: ACME.security.logout_success_handler
             remember_me:
                 secret: '%secret%'
                 lifetime: 604800
                 path: /
                 domain: ~
                 remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
                 always_remember_me: false
                 httponly: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
```

Comment: Is your implementation stateful? In a stateless system (like the example in that link) you wouldn't store the user's identity in the session and would require the API key to be sent with every request. In that case you'd never already be authenticated.

Comment: @mzulch my sistem is not stateless. It is like a social network (session is important).

Answer (score 1):

Every firewall in Symfony can have a logout path, you just need to create an "empty" route with an URL (where "empty" means that the route could be annotated on an action that does nothing, or can be defined without action in a yaml or xml file).
Then, specify that logout URL in your configuration, just like [explained in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#logging-out).

Comment: grazie massimiliano! i have edited my answer with my security.yml. I have already a logout route, but how to perform "auto-logout " on api key authentication?